# Dell Streak 7 Eclipse/adb

Tags: android, adb, android-2.2-froyo, eclipse-adt

Was anybody able to see the Dell Streak in adb devices command? Where I can take the USB drivers? So far this is the only device I am not able to use for development... after 5 hours I am totally tired:(

Thanks for any help.

---

Added later:

I tried to start the driver installer from SD card (dpinst.exe). It fails saying that "Google Inc. (Win USB) Install fail. When I tried to replace the drivers manually from Windows "Device Manager" it says that "Windows found driver, but encountered an error when attempting to install it": Android Composite ADB Inteface. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I got this working using The Manii's ADB + Fastboot drivers from XDA Developers.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=32062253

The actual drivers are located here: http://d-h.st/iqA

This was tested working on my Windows 7 Enterprise x64 machine. I could see the Streak 7 in ADB Devices.